# What verb conveys the concept of 'visited'?

Tags: words

I am trying to say the following: "We also drove around California and visited San Diego, Joshua Tree Park and several beaches."

I think it should be:

> Kariforunia o doraibu shite sandiego nimo ikimashita. Joshua Tree Park
>   to bi-chi o ikutsuka mimashita.

However, I've been told that "Mimashita" is wrong, because it just means "looked/saw." 
I tried the verb "kengaku shimashita" but that apparently is also very similar to "looked/saw."

How can I change my sentence to naturally convey the concept of visiting those places?

PS. I have not used hiragana because my skills in hiragana are still at a beginner level and it's just creating too much confusion for me at this stage. The line is only going to be spoken.

Comment: the word "otozureru" (past tense otozureta) seems to be what you are looking for, but I have never used it, so I am not certain. also, I might choose to say "ikutsuka no biichi o otozureta" , just so the "ikutsuka" can only be applied to the word beach, and not accidentally include Joshua Tree Park... but I might be over-thinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just combine San Diego with the Joshua Tree/beaches. Note that `ikutsuka no` means `a number of`.

> Kariforunia o doraibu shite,  sandiego to Joshua Tree Park to ikutsuka
>   no bi-chi ni ikimashita.

If you mean that on the way to San Diego you went to Joshua Tree and a number of beaches, you could say something like the following. `yottemiru` means `to go to somewhere because it's along the way/convenient`. I.E. Getting to San Diego was the main goal, but Joshua Tree and the beaches were nearby so you decided to go to those as well.

> Kariforunia o doraibu shite,  sandiego ni iki, Joshua Tree Park to
>   ikutsuka no bi-chi ni yottemimashita.

Comment: `何々を行く` sounds a little off to me.  Is there a reason you would use を here instead of に?

Comment: @ajsmart That's what happens when you copy paste stuff... Thanks for pointing it out. I fixed it.